# Can't define friend functions without namespace conflict

Tags: c++, serialization, overloading, qdatastream

I have created a class (MyNodeClass) and now want to add serialization capabilities.  I declare (in mynodeclass.h) my serialization methods as follows:

```
#ifndef MYNODECLASS_H
#define MYNODECLASS_H

#include <QString>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QReadWriteLock>


namespace NS { class MyNodeClass; }
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &out, const MyNodeClass &node);
QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &in, MyNodeClass &node);


namespace NS {

class MyNodeClass
{
public:
    MyNodeClass(quint64 parent, QString name, MyNodeClass::MyEnum type);
    friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &out, const MyNodeClass &node);
    friend QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &in, MyNodeClass &node);

private:
    quint64 m_parent;
    QString m_name;
    int m_type;
    QVariant m_content;
    QReadWriteLock m_lock;
};
}

#endif // MYNODECLASS_H
```

My definitions (in mynodeclass.cpp) are:

```
 #include "mynodeclass.h"


QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &out, const NS::MyNodeClass &node) {
    out
            << node.m_name
            << node.m_type
            << node.m_parent
            << node.m_content;
    return out;
}


QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &in, NS::MyNodeClass &node) {
    QString name;
    int type;
    quint64 parent;
    QVariant contents;

    in
            >> name
            >> type
            >> parent
            >> contents;
    node = NS::MyNodeClass(parent,name,type);

    return in;
}

using namespace NS;

MyNodeClass::MyNodeClass(quint64 parent, QString name, MyNodeClass::MyEnum type) {}
```

The compiler complains that my operator<< cannot access private members of NS::MyNodeClass.  That means the signatures aren't lining up.  I've tried every combination of namespace related changes but can't figure it out.  I've modelled my code after [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934226/class-friend-function-inside-a-namespace)

How should the friend functions be defined so that there is no complaint about namespace or access to private members?  (Please note that all examples I could find use a single file, so splitting into .h and .cpp is part of what needs to be addressed)

Comment: You could do one better. Make it a [mre].

Comment: The good thing about a MRE is that we can copy, compile and give you immediate feedback. Most of us are used to using debugging tools and when I start looking at a problem, i throw it in the debugger and see what is says.

Comment: I found a SO post explaning problems in streaming enum type so I eliminated that part of question.  Remaining part of question relates to namespaces, so I clarified question

Comment: Your header declares `ns::operator<<` as a friend of `MyNodeClass`; this function is never defined. Your source file defines `::operator<<` (in global namespace) - this function was not declared a friend of `MyNodeClass`, and so cannot access its private members. Defining these functions in namespace `ns` is the right thing to do - can you show the warnings produced when you try that?

Comment: I have reworked the code per another posts which suggests how to solve this.  But still have namespace issues.

Answer (score 0):

You declare 2 `operator >>` in different namespace, only the one in `namespace NS` is `friend`.

get rid of your "forward declarations":

```
// Remove that
namespace NS { class MyNodeClass; }
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &out, const MyNodeClass &node);
QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &in, MyNodeClass &node);
```

and implement `NS::operator<<`:

```
namespace NS {

QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &out, const NS::MyNodeClass &node) {
    return out << node.m_name
               << node.m_type
               << node.m_parent
               << node.m_content;
}

QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &in, NS::MyNodeClass &node) {
    QString name;
    int type;
    quint64 parent;
    QVariant contents;

    in >> name
       >> type
       >> parent
       >> contents;
    node = NS::MyNodeClass(parent, name, type);

    return in;
}


MyNodeClass::MyNodeClass(quint64 parent, QString name, MyNodeClass::MyEnum type) {}
```

Comment: You have removed friend in front of operator definitions - mine won't compile with out.  Why?  Aren't those necessary to access private members, and, so compiler doesn't think we are overloading bitwise shift?

Comment: With friend added it compiles, but when I try to serialize runtime message QVariant unable to save type NS::MyNodeClass.  Is there anything missing in terms of registering a meta type etc?