# std:hash with access to private members of a class

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, stdset, stdhash

I would like to hash a class that has two private members e.g.:

foo.h

```
class Foo {
    private:
        std::string a;
        std::string b;

    public:
        Foo (std::string a, std::string b);
        bool operator==(const Foo& other) const;
        bool operator!=(const Foo& other) const;
        std::size_t operator()(const Foo& ) const;
};

namespace std {
    template <> struct hash<Foo> {
        std::size_t operator()(const Foo& cp) const;
    };
}
```

foo.cpp

```
Foo::Foo (std::string _a, std::string _b) {
    this->a = _a;
    this->b = _b;
}

bool Foo::operator== (const Foo& other) const {
    return this->a == other.a && this->b == other.b;
}

bool Foo::operator!= (const Foo& other) const {
    return !operator==(other);
}

std::size_t std::hash<Foo>::operator()(Foo const& foo) const {
    std::string f = foo.a; // << This wont compile!
    return 1;
}
```

In C++ how is hashing of `Foo` typically done when that final hash function doesn't have access to the private member of foo.

Feel free to include boost or abseil in your answer.

Comment: What if Foo had a public member function called `std::size_t get_hash() const;` ...?

Comment: You can use a `friend` declaration (note that [this requires forward-declaring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10934412/1968) both your class and the `std::hash` specialisation). That’s IMHO better than polluting the interface by adding another unnecessary member function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is declare `std::hash<Foo>` as a `friend` of `Foo`:

```cpp
class Foo {
 private:
  std::string a;
  std::string b;

 public:
  Foo(std::string a, std::string b);
  bool operator==(const Foo& other) const;
  bool operator!=(const Foo& other) const;
  std::size_t operator()(const Foo&) const;

  friend std::hash<Foo>;
};
```